# Suggestion for Stochastic Process book

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process

I am looking for Stochastic process book for self study. I read first two chapters from Stochastic Process by Sheldon M. Ross(2nd edition) but face a lot of problem to understand the exercise problems. Can anyone have the solution manual pdf of this book or can suggest some other book which has some examples.

Comment: *Adventures in Stochastic Processes* by Sidney Resnick.

Comment: Going through *many* different sources is helpful.  On top of what others have said http://www.randomservices.org/random/index.html has much of that material in Ross, and has interactive applet examples.  Karlin and Taylor's "A First Course" is also very good but somewhat more difficult than Ross.  The MIT OCW course mentioned below leans on Ross's book a lot in attribution, and has solutions to assignments.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an extansive discussion on the Poisson process, you'll be able to find it in "Discrete Stochastic Process", 2nd draft by R.G. Gallager (you should find it in the course material at https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-262-discrete-stochastic-processes-spring-2011/video-lectures/). I personnaly enjoyed this book a lot since Gallager has, following my opinion, a very bright understanding of probability theory.